# how should i approach my boss with my resignation letter?

Tags: resignation

So the time has come for me to hand my notice in, as I'm going back to the company I left 6 months ago returning to a higher position making more money and with a good training program set out for me.

This same week the new building has been finished, and I am being told about my office moving into the new building. They want to start making plans to get me moved by the end of the month

I will be handing my notice in on Friday and I'm not sure how to deal with the situation as I can see this becoming an issue with everything they are starting to put in place.

I want to give an extra week of notice (2 weeks instead of 1 as I'm in the probationary period) because I don't want to just drop it on them so to speak

However, I'm not sure on how to to tell my boss as I feel guilty knowing I am leaving as they are making plans for me

Comment: I think perhaps the key here is to not be worried. The company would be fine without you in the long run, and that's not a personal insult, they'll simply move on. As for the "plans they have for you", better to tell them now before they get started on those plans, rather than wasting time to complete them.

Comment: A move is not that much planning.  I would not change timing.

Answer (score 3):

**Approach it like any other resignation**

There, that's the simple answer. I'll go into detail below.

I'm assuming you are some sort of team leader/manager from your comments.

> although this same week the new building has been finished and I am being told about my office moving into the new building and they want to start making plans to get me moved by the end of the month
>
> I will be handing my notice in on Friday and im not sure how to deal with the situation as I can see this becoming an issue with everything they are starting to put in place.

Moving offices is purely a logistical exercise. It doesn't seem to me, from what little we have been told, that you leaving will have a major impact on moving people to different desks in a different building. The company will have plans in place and probably know where everyone is going to sit anyway. Or if this up to you, you will have done this already.

> I am giving an extra week of notice (2 weeks instead of 1 as im in
> probation) as I don't want to just drop them in it so to speak
>
> but im not sure on how to to tell my boss as I feel guilty knowing im
> leaving as they are making plans for me

I don't want to sound harsh but you clearly haven't been there long enough to truly drop them in it. Otherwise they would have got you off probation and tied down to a longer notice period. I'm guessing you aren't director level as you are moving for a promotion, so I am guessing while your departure may set them back, it will probably be able to

Don't give the extra notice. What more could you achieve in 1 week? Just make sure any loose ends are tied up and anything you can't do in that time are documented clearly so whoever takes your role on can do what they need to do.

Comment: Just like any other resignation...in writing....say nothing bad about them if exit interview is conducted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry unduly about the place you are leaving. They're not your problem.

Just resign professionally, hand in your notice, do what you can to make the transition smooth and focus on where you are going. Everything else will take care of itself, anything that doesn't isn't your responsibility.